# Fastlane with multiple certificates

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

Let us say that we have two valid certificates and two corresponding provisioning profiles for a single application.

Let us say that we need this setup for reasons unrelated to the question.

How can we use fastlane / fastlane match to use either one or another depending on some additional conditions (to be specified in fastfile)?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate / provisioning profiles can be mapped by `app id`, and `build schemes`, which named with `release`, or custom names like `appStore`, `appStore_forA`, `appStore_forB`.

I has an app, with 2 different `app id`. ex, `app_A`, and `app_B`. I distinguish them by build scheme. One is `appStore_A`, and another is `appStore_B`.

In my `fastlane` file, it likes following.

```
// For build app_A, and upload to TestFlight.
lane: app_A do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key( /* for `pilot` auth */)

  match(type: "appstore", readonly: true, git_url: "ooxx@match.storage")       

  gym(
     clean: true,
     scheme: "appStore_A",
     configuration: "AppStore",
     workspace: "app.xcworkspace",
  )

  pilot(
     app_identifier: "com.app_A",
     api_key: api_key
  )
end

// For build app_B, and upload to TestFlight.
lane: app_B do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key( /* for `pilot` auth */)

  match(type: "appstore", readonly: true, git_url: "ooxx@match.storage")       

  gym(
     clean: true,
     scheme: "appStore_B",
     configuration: "AppStore",
     workspace: "app.xcworkspace",
  )

  pilot(
     app_identifier: "com.app_B",
     api_key: api_key
  )
end
```

`app_A`, and `app_B` use the same `app.xcworkspace`, but they are in different `scheme` and different app `target`.

Comment: I would  like to avoid any dependence on Xcode files when making this decision. So I have the same app ID, the same schemes, etc. but I have two different certs and two different prov profiles (with names) and would like to choose among them based on some external criteria.